# Changes in one Project files are changing source files in another Project

Tags: ios, xcode, project, xcode6

I started `ProjectB`, which is very similar to `ProjectA` that I had done previously.

So I wanted to use about 75% of the same `ViewControllers` and code for `ProjectB` that I had **already created in `ProjectA`**.  So I **added the files to `ProjectB`**.

For whatever reason, when I'm making changes in my `ProjectB` files that I pulled from `ProjectA`, they are actually updating the `ProjectA` files too, and vice versa.

I'm not really sure how to get that to stop happening. I assumed once the files got into `ProjectB`, they would be silo'd only in `ProjectB` now.

But thats not happening.  And if I right click on `WebViewControllerA.m` file that is inside of `ProjectB` to "Show in Finder", it points to the `ProjectA` folder.

I can't figure out how to just **make `ProjectB` files a separate** entity.  Can you help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Xcode creates references as default. You should copy the files you want from **project A** to edit in **project B**

Comment: Thanks for the response David!  So I ended up copying them after I realized they were referenced, but I seem to have not done it correct because they are still referencing each other.  What is the best way to copy them in, just so I make sure I'm doing it right?  Is it to copy and paste straight in to the ProjectB folder?  And is there any way to verify that they aren't still referencing each other other than just making changes and one file and then going to check to see if it changed the other projects file?

Comment: What I do when I'm in your case it : 1) Right click on files I want -> Show in Finder. 2) I copy them 3) I past them in my new project's folder. 4) I import them in my Project B from the new copied files.

Comment: This is what I've done, per your suggestion... 1) I removed all of the files in `ProjectB` that I had incorrectly gotten from `ProjectA`. 2) I opened up the folder from `ProjectA' that has all of the files I want, I select all that I need, then right click and select "Copy". 3) I then go to `ProjectB` folder and paste them in. 4) I then open my `ProjectB` Workspace

Comment: Did I get everything right so far?  And to "Import" them, do I do File -> Add Files to ProjectB ?

Comment: Yes and yes, but only removed the references, not deleting the files ;)

Comment: Which part of my process would I do something with removing the references, is that an explicit action?  Sorry for needing such detail! I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Oh maybe your referring to step 1 of mine when I removed all of the files...  I deleted them instead of what your suggesting I could have done in just removing references? Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: When removing files it ask if you want to move to trash or delete only references. If you do to loose your files you have to delete only references.